# Render Powershell results in Windows Explorer

Tags: powershell, windows-explorer

I have a Powershell script that searches for images and displays the results as a text list.

Is it possible to send this result list to Windows Explorer so that the images can be rendered as thumbnails?

I'd also like to be able to sort the results on fields like filesize, date modified, directory which Windows Explorer provides.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not really.
Powershell (or .net) doesent really have a image gallery of sorts, but what you can do to mitigate this is the following:

1. Get full path of all images
2. Create `$TempGallery = new-item "$env:temp\chooseAname" -itemtype directory -force`. this will create the folder. -force forces creation of all parent folders if they do not exist
3. For each image, copy it to `$TempGallery`:`$Files|copy-item -destination $TempGallery.fullname`
4. to open explorer to that location, go `explorer $tempgallery.fullname`
5. if you want you can have a `$none = read-host 'View files and press enter when done'` and then cleanup after.

I'm pretty sure you can do some monkeybusiness to force explorer to view the files different (IE force thumbnail view), but depending on your soultion, how this will affect the global settings of explorer file listings in other directories and the users of this, i'm guessing they could change the view thumbnails themselves or open them at will.

The other way if to do the steps above, but instead of opening explorer, you open a filepicker to `$tempgallery`. that way you can also get the end user to pick one or more files, if this is your goal. [Hey, Scripting Guy! Can I Open a File Dialog Box with Windows PowerShell?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-can-i-open-a-file-dialog-box-with-windows-powershell/)

---

However if this is not good enough, then you could use the listview funcionality of windows forms, but that's another monster like [this](https://audministrator.wordpress.com/2020/06/07/powershell-gui-listview-icons-example/).

(but atleast you don't have to copy all files to a temp dir)

Comment: Ok thanks. The temp directory might not work if there are two or more files with the same name or if the search result list is quite large. I'll look into Windows Forms.